# In the Authorizenet SDK version 1.1.8 for PHP Is there a way to charge a card using a customer payment profile?

Tags: payment, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I have been up and down through the SDK code and have the ability to add customer profiles and payment profiles for them but I can't see anywhere, where I can charge a card or create a subscription from a customer profile and customer payment profile.  Does anyone have an answer for this for either the create subscription, or charge a card, using the PHP SDK.  Please understand, giving me an interactive web example using AuthorizeNet's web API is not helpful here.  The requirements are that it has to be done through the PHP SDK as we cannot have card user interaction past the point of the customer profile and customer payment profile creation.

Answer (score 1):

First off need to define the normal credentials used for SDK requests

```
if (!defined("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID")) define("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID", {authorizenet_api_login_id};
if (!defined("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY")) define("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY",  {authorizenet_transaction_key};
```

Then create the transaction and set the fields.

```
$transaction = new AuthorizeNetTransaction;
$transaction->amount = $amount;
$transaction->customerProfileId = $customerProfileId;
$transaction->customerPaymentProfileId = $customerPaymentProfileId;
// next line may be optional depending on your situation
$transaction->customerShippingAddressId = $customerShippingAddressId;
```

Then process the transaction

```
$request = new AuthorizeNetCIM;
    $response = $request->createCustomerProfileTransaction("AuthCapture", $transaction);

if ($response->xml->messages->resultCode=="Ok") echo "It Was Approved"
```

;